# Animated gif form parametric plot

Tags: animation, debugging

I need to create an animated gif for the following function.

```
rx1=((-T ω Cos[T ω] + Sin[T ω]))/(2ω^2)
ry1=(-2 + 2 Cos[T ω] + T ω Sin[T ω])/(2ω^2)
pulsefrequency=200000*π; τpulse1= 20*10^-6;
```

When I use

```
   Animate[
  Show[ParametricPlot[{rx1, ry1}/. ω -> pulsefrequency, 
  {T,0,u},PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}],
   Graphics[
   {Blue, PointSize[0.02], 
    Point[{rx1, ry1}  /. ω -> 
          pulsefrequency /. T -> u]}]], 
   {u, 0, τpulse1}, AnimationRepetitions -> 1]
```

It works well but when for getting an animated gif, I replace Animate command with Table and then it ceases to work

```
Table[ Show[
ParametricPlot[{rx1, ry1}  /. ω -> pulsefrequency, {T, 0, u /. u -> s}, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{-0.010, 0.010}, {-0.010, 0.010}}, Background -> RGBColor[100.0, 100.0, 100.0]],Graphics[{PointSize[.025], Hue[0], Point[{rx1, ry1}  /. ω -> pulsefrequency  /. T -> s]}]] , {s, 0, τpulse1, τpulse1/10}]
```

The output that I recieve is

```
{Show[ParametricPlot[{rx1, ry1} /. E0 -> pulseamp /. ω -> 
   pulsefrequency /. m -> mass /. q -> charge, {T, 0, 
u /. u -> s}, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{-0.01, 0.01}, {-0.01, 0.01}}, Background -> RGBColor[100., 100., 100.]], \!\(\*GraphicsBox[{Hue[0], PointSize[0.025], PointBox[{0., 0.}]}]\)], **followed by the list of the images**
```

I have spend hours to figure out how to just get the animated image rather than the command. I am not sure whats going wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 7):

I believe the issue relates to increment size., e.g.

```
   an = Table[
   Show[ParametricPlot[{rx1, ry1} /. \[Omega] -> pulsefrequency, {T, 
      0, u}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}], 
    Graphics[{Blue, PointSize[0.02], 
      Point[{rx1, ry1} /. \[Omega] -> pulsefrequency /. T -> u]}], 
    PlotRange -> {{-1.5 10^-11, 1.4 10^-11}, {-1.6  10^-11, 
       10^-11}}], {u, 10^-6, \[Tau]pulse1, 10^-7}];
```

[image]

You can modify gif as required. The above was just exported as gif.

Comment: Many thanks ubpdqn. U solved my problem